# Design Pattern for a Wrapper to Message Queue Services

Tags: design-patterns, rabbitmq, zeromq, amazon-sqs, mq

I want to design a wrapper to talk to Message Queue(s)f. The implementation of the wrapper should be generic enough so that client of the library doesn't have to make any code changes if they want to switch from one MQ provider (for example *RabbitMQ*) to another MQ Service (say *Amazon SQS*).

What Design Pattern would you recommend for the library and why?

Comment: [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html)?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [Adapter](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) design pattern.

Let's say you have two queueing technologies: Q1 and Q2. Each of them provides different methods to interact with them. The class design looks like the following:

- Create an interface, say `IQueue`, with generic methods. For e.g., getMessage(), postMessage() and deleteMessage().
- For Q1, create an adapter that is composed of Q1-client and extends `IQueue`. Similarly, for Q2.
- Code your application to `IQueue`. Then, switching from Q1 to Q2 simply involves replacing one adapter class with another.